# Pandora Api auth.partnerLogin giving error

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, pandora

I recently stumbled across [some documentation for the unofficial Pandora API.](https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/json/#)

I decided to try this with Python 3.

After heading to [the Authentication page](https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/json/authentication/) I saw that I first had to verfiy that the service was available in my country so I did this.

```
import requests
import urllib

url = "http://internal-tuner.pandora.com/services/json/?method=test.checkLicensing"

res = requests.post(url)

print(res.status_code)
print(res.content)
```

It prints out:

```
<Response [200]>
b'{"stat":"ok","result":{"isAllowed":true}}'
```

Right. So I'm allowed to use the partner service.

Next I saw that I had to get a **Partner Login**.

So I got the info it said I needed from [the Partners page](https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/json/partners/#partners).

### Note this is not my login info. This was partner info I was told to choose from in the documentation.

```
username = "android"
password = "AC7IBG09A3DTSYM4R41UJWL07VLN8JI7"
deviceModel = "android-generic"
```

Next, the documentation says to send a post request to one of the following links as the **base** url:

- http://tuner.pandora.com/services/json/
- https://tuner.pandora.com/services/json/
- http://internal-tuner.pandora.com/services/json/
- https://internal-tuner.pandora.com/services/json/

Now to encode the url parameters and put them after the base url.
It says I should take the above `username`, `password`, `deviceModel`, the method I want to call (for partner login it says it is "auth.PartnerLogin", and the version (it says pass in the string "5") and url encode them.

So I set up the url params in urlencoded format and fire off a POST request:

```
import requests
import urllib

url = "http://internal-tuner.pandora.com/services/json/?"

username = "android"
password = "AC7IBG09A3DTSYM4R41UJWL07VLN8JI7"
deviceModel = "android-generic"

data = {
    "method": "auth.partnerLogin",
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "deviceModel": deviceModel,
    "version": "5"
}

url += urllib.parse.urlencode(data)

res = requests.post(url)

print("url:", url)
print("response:", res)
print("content:", res.content)
```

But when I do it prints this out and tells me there was an error:

```
url: http://internal-tuner.pandora.com/services/json/?method=auth.partnerLogin&username=android&password=AC7IBG09A3DTSYM4R41UJWL07VLN8JI7&deviceModel=android-generic&version=5
response: <Response [200]>
content: b'{"stat":"fail","message":"An unexpected error occurred","code":9}'
```

Has anyone else used this Api before?
Why am I getting an error? Am I missing something here?
Apparently [pithos](https://github.com/pithos/pithos) uses this api, and it is loading music fine for me.

Can anybody point me in the right direction here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you passing data as parameters and using incorrect url.

Proper curl request:

```
########## REQUEST ##########
curl  -i  --data '{ "username": "android", "password": "AC7IBG09A3DTSYM4R41UJWL07VLN8JI7", "deviceModel": "android-generic", "version": "5", "includeUrls": true }' -X POST 'https://tuner.pandora.com:443/services/json/?method=auth.partnerLogin'   -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -A 'pinobar'
########## OUTPUT ##########
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 04 Jan 2018 03:46:54 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 741
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=0
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{"stat":"ok","result":{"syncTime":"f6f071bb4b886bc3545fbd66701b8d38","deviceProperties":{"followOnAdRefreshInterval":3,"ooyala":{"streamingPercentage":0,"streamingWhitelist":[534051315],"videoAdBufferRetryCount":3,"videoAdLoadingTimeout":2,"videoAdPlayTimeout":8},"videoAdUniqueInterval":0,"videoAdStartInterval":180,"optionalFeatures":{"optionalFeature":[{"feature":"useAudioProxy2","enabled":"false","platformVersionRange":{"low":"4.0","high":"5.0.0"},"productVersionRange":{"low":"1.6","high":"*"}}]},"adRefreshInterval":3,"videoAdRefreshInterval":870},"partnerAuthToken":"VADEjNzUq9Ew9HUkIzUT489kVe9kjo0If3","partnerId":"42","stationSkipUnit":"hour","urls":{"autoComplete":"http://autocomplete.pandora.com/search"},"stationSkipLimit":6}}
```

I would suggest use  [urllib2 sample](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html).

Here working sample for our case:

```
import json
import urllib2

username    = "android"
password    = "AC7IBG09A3DTSYM4R41UJWL07VLN8JI7"
deviceModel = "android-generic"
url         = "https://tuner.pandora.com:443/services/json/?method=auth.partnerLogin"

values = {
    "username"   : username,
    "password"   : password,
    "deviceModel": deviceModel,
    "version"    : "5"
}

data = json.dumps(values)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = response.read()

print("data:", data)
print("url:", url)
print("response:", response)
print("content:", content)
```

Output:

```
('url:', 'https://tuner.pandora.com:443/services/json/?method=auth.partnerLogin')
('response:', <addinfourl at 4509594832 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x10c7c0bd0>>)
('content:', '{"stat":"ok","result":{"stationSkipLimit":6,"partnerId":"42","partnerAuthToken":"VAEIniGnwSV1exsWHgUcsQgV5HA63B1nFA","syncTime":"4663310634ae885f45f489b2ab918a66","deviceProperties":{"followOnAdRefreshInterval":3,"ooyala":{"streamingPercentage":0,"streamingWhitelist":[534051315],"videoAdBufferRetryCount":3,"videoAdLoadingTimeout":2,"videoAdPlayTimeout":8},"videoAdUniqueInterval":0,"videoAdStartInterval":180,"optionalFeatures":{"optionalFeature":[{"feature":"useAudioProxy2","enabled":"false","platformVersionRange":{"low":"4.0","high":"5.0.0"},"productVersionRange":{"low":"1.6","high":"*"}}]},"adRefreshInterval":3,"videoAdRefreshInterval":870},"stationSkipUnit":"hour"}}')
```

Comment: Thank you much sir. I had found this out when reading into the source code for `pithos` a couple of days after posting the question. I had meant to update my post (and add an answer) as to help anyone else with this problem, as I could find no help with this other than reading into the source of pithos itself.

Comment: I will mark your answer as the solution so anyone with the same problem can get a little push in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks and happy coding!